# Storyboard randomly modifying contraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

Every now and then I notice my storyboard has changes ('m' beside it). I run my app and find that my views are out of position. If I check the difference between the previous and current versions of the Storybaord XML in the version editor it appears that Storyboard has made changes when I have touched nothing in the file. I have to discard these changes to get things working again. I have to admit that my layout contains warnings. It's incredibly complex (lots of views) but it works and this particularly layout only contains warnings, no errors. Has anyone else noticed this behaviour? It's incredibly annoying. I can fix it by discarding the changes but that's not exactly ideal.

Comment: Yeah, I also have the "M" besides the storyboard, it's a stupid thing to be honest, but the position of the views are correct, might be a bug of Xcode. Also it's possible that you move them by mistake when you opened the storyboard.

Comment: "Also it's possible that you move them by mistake when you opened the storyboard." I considered this but last time it happened immediately after I fixed it and hadn't touched the mouse or keyboard. It's getting pretty irritating. Costs me 1-2 mins every time it happens.

Comment: i'm also had similar behavior. All the time i'm re run xcode project, storyboard change my UITableViewCell sizes.

Comment: Glad to hear I'm not the only one! Do either of you have warnings/errors with your auto-layout?

Comment: noticed the same... Xcode seems to randomly change constraints... maybe taking a look into the raw XML of the storyboards also could provide insights to this issue.

Comment: @nburk the raw XML via version editor is how I revert the changes easily. When the issue happens and you open the version editor there is always one section with lots (5-10) changes. I discard each of these to solve the issue. I can't see anything that points to the cause unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with storyboard for quite some time. I've faced the issue of getting 'M' besides storyboard. What i did is set the layout constraints correctly and removed all warnings related to auto layout from storyboard but it is not necessary to remove them what i realised later. You just commit the code as you will be using git copy. Once commit is done 'M' will be gone. The reason you are getting 'M' even if you didn't touch the storyboard after you've set layout with constraints can be due to three reasons.
1.) You might be working on local copy and while creating the project you might not have unchecked the git repository.
[image]
All you need to do is uncheck while you create new project.
2.) If you are working on source of svn, then you need to commit your all the files along with your storyboard.It will remove the 'M' displaying besides your storyboard. 
3.) Every time u open your storyboard the id in xml changes so due to this reason u r getting 'M' besides storyboard.